# Unique entries in a filtered excel list

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I am using a list in Excel to document working time. There are multiple rows with the same date value in the column `date` but different other values in other columns.

I am using the following function to get the count of working days by getting the count of unique entries of the column `date` in the range of the cell D5 to the cell D36 to multiply the result with 8 hours of work per day and divide it through 24 hours to use the result as a time value (`[HH:mm]`):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIF(D5:D36;D5:D36)))*8/24
```

The result is correct for an unfiltered list. But in case of filtering for specific days on the column `date`, this function does not ignore the hidden rows.

Comment: Try: `=LET(x, D5:D36,SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(x,SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(x,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x))-1,0,1))))<>""))/3)`

Comment: This code results in an error `501`.

Comment: `501` error are you trying to use it in `VBA`? I am not sure how excel formula will return error code `501`